# AttributeError: /home/hp/anaconda3/lib/libxgboost.so: undefined symbol: XGDMatrixSetDenseInfo

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost, ensemble-learning

I have installed `XGBoost` with `pip3`.

While trying to run this line:

```
clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=xgb.XGBClassifier(use_label_encoder =False), param_grid=params, scoring = 'accuracy', cv=20).fit(data_train, label_train)
```

I get this error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-718a4a11a2ba> in <module>
      4     startTime = time.time()
      5 
----> 6     clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=xgb.XGBClassifier(use_label_encoder =False), param_grid=params, scoring = 'accuracy', cv=20).fit(data_train, label_train)
      7     print(clf.best_estimator_)
      8     print('--------------------------------------------------')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
     62             if extra_args <= 0:
---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
     64 
     65             # extra_args > 0

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    878             refit_start_time = time.time()
    879             if y is not None:
--> 880                 self.best_estimator_.fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    881             else:
    882                 self.best_estimator_.fit(X, **fit_params)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/core.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
    420         for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args):
    421             kwargs[k] = arg
--> 422         return f(**kwargs)
    423 
    424     return inner_f

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, base_margin, eval_set, eval_metric, early_stopping_rounds, verbose, xgb_model, sample_weight_eval_set, feature_weights, callbacks)
    901         self.n_features_in_ = self._features_count
    902 
--> 903         train_dmatrix, evals = self._wrap_evaluation_matrices(
    904             X, y, group=None, sample_weight=sample_weight, base_margin=base_margin,
    905             feature_weights=feature_weights,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py in _wrap_evaluation_matrices(self, X, y, group, sample_weight, base_margin, feature_weights, eval_set, sample_weight_eval_set, eval_group, label_transform)
    263 
    264         y = label_transform(y)
--> 265         train_dmatrix = DMatrix(data=X, label=y, weight=sample_weight,
    266                                 base_margin=base_margin,
    267                                 missing=self.missing, nthread=self.n_jobs)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/core.py in __init__(self, data, label, weight, base_margin, missing, silent, feature_names, feature_types, nthread, enable_categorical)
    507         self.handle = handle
    508 
--> 509         self.set_info(label=label, weight=weight, base_margin=base_margin)
    510 
    511         self.feature_names = feature_names

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/core.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
    420         for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args):
    421             kwargs[k] = arg
--> 422         return f(**kwargs)
    423 
    424     return inner_f

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/core.py in set_info(self, label, weight, base_margin, group, label_lower_bound, label_upper_bound, feature_names, feature_types, feature_weights)
    528         '''Set meta info for DMatrix.'''
    529         if label is not None:
--> 530             self.set_label(label)
    531         if weight is not None:
    532             self.set_weight(weight)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/core.py in set_label(self, label)
    657         """
    658         from .data import dispatch_meta_backend
--> 659         dispatch_meta_backend(self, label, 'label', 'float')
    660 
    661     def set_weight(self, weight):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/data.py in dispatch_meta_backend(matrix, data, name, dtype)
    674         data = data.values.astype('float')
    675         assert len(data.shape) == 1 or data.shape[1] == 0 or data.shape[1] == 1
--> 676         _meta_from_numpy(data, name, dtype, handle)
    677         return
    678     if _is_dlpack(data):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/data.py in _meta_from_numpy(data, field, dtype, handle)
    598     ptr = interface['data'][0]
    599     ptr = ctypes.c_void_p(ptr)
--> 600     _check_call(_LIB.XGDMatrixSetDenseInfo(
    601         handle,
    602         c_str(field),

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py in __getattr__(self, name)
    392         if name.startswith('__') and name.endswith('__'):
    393             raise AttributeError(name)
--> 394         func = self.__getitem__(name)
    395         setattr(self, name, func)
    396         return func

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py in __getitem__(self, name_or_ordinal)
    397 
    398     def __getitem__(self, name_or_ordinal):
--> 399         func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
    400         if not isinstance(name_or_ordinal, int):
    401             func.__name__ = name_or_ordinal

AttributeError: /home/hp/anaconda3/lib/libxgboost.so: undefined symbol: XGDMatrixSetDenseInfo
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you get the same issue if you run the GridSearchCV separately to fitting the model? Is this code run 'as is' or is it part of a function? If you could please provide the code you are using and further information on your system/setup you will likely get a better answer.

Comment: Got same error. Could you plz guide me how I should uninstall xgboost and reinstall it without harming any other installations?

Comment: In my experience the best approach is to uninstall system-wide xgboost (e.g. `pip3 uninstall xgboost`) and create a new anaconda environment and install xgboost / SKlearn using `conda install py-xgboost scikit-learn` (along with any other packages you need, e.g. pandas, numpy, pylint, jupyter, matplotlib, keras, etc)

Comment: I'm getting the same error message with xgboost 1.6.1. Any solution?

Comment: I can't remember what I did that time. Most probably I followed jared_mamrot's advice and got it solved for me.